# Twitter API libraries for desktop apps?

Tags: c++, python, api, twitter

I'm looking for a way to fetch recent posts from twitter. Really I just want to be able to grab and store new posts about a certain topic from twitter in a text file. Are there any current programs or libraries which do this (prefrably C++, although python is ok too)? What would people suggest?

Comment: There are official Twitter APis for accessing Twitter data...why scraping?

Comment: I don't think he really meant scraping although he used the word.

Comment: no idea what he means...I read what was written down...not into mindreading

Comment: @AndreasJung If you read things in context, it often does not matter which word they use because _in context_, you can still get the gist of what they mean. Instead of insulting the person, why don't you use your brain a little more and perhaps, give them the correct word to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can check the API docs [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries), some of the projects that are listed there:

**C++**

[QTweetLib](http://github.com/minimoog/QTweetLib) - C++ Qt based Twitter library

[QTwitLib](http://twitlib.googlecode.com/) by Bradley Lackey & Maks Zolin. C++ library for Linux, Windows, and Mac. Currently in beta. Unmaintained since 2009.

[Twitcurl](http://code.google.com/p/twitcurl/) by Mahesh. C++ library which uses curl library for HTTP interaction with Twitter API.

**Python**

[python-twitter here](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/)

[oauth-python-twitter2](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-python-twitter2/) by Konpaku Kogasa. Combines python-twitter and oauth-python-twitter to create an evolved OAuth Pokemon. Unmaintained since 2010.

[python-twyt](http://andrewprice.me.uk/projects/twyt/) by Andrew Price. BSD licensed Twitter API interface library and command line client. Project discontinued.

[twitty-twister](http://github.com/dustin/twitty-twister/tree/master) by Dustin Sallings. A Twisted interface to Twitter.

[twython](http://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/tree/master) by Ryan McGrath. REST and Search library inspired by python-twitter.

[Tweepy](http://github.com/joshthecoder/tweepy) by Josh Roesslein. Supports OAuth, Search API, Streaming API.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at some of them, wasn't sure if they actually supported scrapting though.