# Signing twitter user stream request with OAuth

Tags: oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to sign a request with OAuth. I read a lot of articles on it, but I don't know how to actually use it right now.

I have this URL: https://userstream.twitter.com/2/user.json And I want to call it for a certain user. I have an app (with Consumer key en secret) and the API key for the account I want to use. So the only thing left to do is sign it.
I used this page: http://hueniverse.com/2008/10/beginners-guide-to-oauth-part-iv-signing-requests/ and got a code block that looked like this one:

```
GET /photos?size=original&file=vacation.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: photos.example.net:80
Authorization: OAuth realm="http://photos.example.net/photos",
    oauth_consumer_key="dpf43f3p2l4k3l03",
    oauth_token="nnch734d00sl2jdk",
    oauth_nonce="kllo9940pd9333jh",
    oauth_timestamp="1191242096",
    oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
    oauth_version="1.0",
    oauth_signature="tR3%2BTy81lMeYAr%2FFid0kMTYa%2FWM%3D"
```

However, cURL does not accept that. How do I construct something that will work with cURL?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I don't really need cURL, just comething that I can use with C++ on GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I've curled a Twitter request from the (Windows) command line, and had to add an OAuth authorization header, I've done it like this:

```
curl -k "https://userstream.twitter.com/2/user.json" --header "Authorization: OAuth realm=""Twitter API"",oauth_consumer_key=""dpf43f3p2l4k3l03"",oauth_token=""nnch734d00sl2jdk"",oauth_nonce=""kllo9940pd9333jh"",oauth_timestamp=""1191242096"",oauth_signature_method=""HMAC-SHA1"",oauth_version=""1.0"",oauth_signature=""tR3%2BTy81lMeYAr%2FFid0kMTYa%2FWM%3D"""
```

Of course, if you're using [that Java applet](http://hueniverse.com/2008/10/beginners-guide-to-oauth-part-iv-signing-requests/), be sure you've set the time as close to the correct time as possible, specified your OAuth credentials, and set the URL part appropriately before substituting the output values into the command line above.

```
Method: GET
URI Scheme: https
Host Name: userstream.twitter.com
Port: 443
Request Path: /2/user.json
Parameters: [remove all]
```

Note in the header output that you must manually change the realm to **Twitter API**, but all the other output values should be correct.

Additionally, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739006/twitter-api-libraries-for-desktop-apps/5739050#5739050) has a good selection of C++ Twitter libraries you could try, although the link to the Twitter documentation that lists is out of date -- [here's the latest](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#cplusplus).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think it works, I don't get unauthorized errors anymore. However, I don't get data either. When I issue the command, it runs for about 3 seconds and then terminates, bringing me back to the prompt. Is this supposed to happen? How do I get the data?

Comment: UPDATE: So I tried it with wget and I got 
--2011-06-13 14:08:31--  https://userstream.twitter.com/2/user.json
Resolving userstream.twitter.com... 199.59.148.139
Connecting to userstream.twitter.com|199.59.148.139|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error
2011-06-13 14:08:33 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error.

Is my request malformed or is the API down? Your example gives a 500 too.

Comment: http://dev.twitter.com/status shows that everything looks good, but I think I've only seen statuses in the 400s, and the going direction from Twitter is to report all 500s, so I think it's a problem on Twitter's end. Could have something to do with the earthquake in New Zealand that happened today.

Comment: Somebody else ran into a 500 today as well: http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/ebd5aced1f9b3b1f#

Comment: Interesting that would happen just now. However, I'm also running TweetDeck right now, which uses userstreams and works fine. But since twitter bought TweetDeck, wouldn't be strange if they have a separate server for it...